# How to use a flag in a SQL function to sort results in ascending or descending order?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have the following SQL function which orders results by a specific column depending on which flag is set:

```sql
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_deals(
  search text, 
  hasura_session json, 
  order_direction boolean DEFAULT false, 
  order_by_full_name boolean DEFAULT false, 
  order_by_email boolean DEFAULT false, 
  order_by_deal_status boolean DEFAULT false, 
  order_by_loan_status boolean DEFAULT false, 
  order_by_created_at boolean DEFAULT false, 
  limit_param integer DEFAULT 8, 
  offset_param integer DEFAULT 0
) RETURNS SETOF sort_types.__deals LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$ BEGIN RETURN QUERY 
SELECT 
  deal.id, 
  deal."_createdAt", 
  deal."dealStatusID", 
  dp."partyID", 
  party."partyRoleID", 
  pp."personID", 
  person."fullName", 
  person."primaryEmail", 
  loan.id AS "loanID", 
  loan."loanStatusID" 
FROM 
  deal 
  JOIN "DealParty" dp ON deal.id = dp."dealID" 
  JOIN party ON dp."partyID" = party.id 
  JOIN "PartyPerson" pp ON party.id = pp."partyID" 
  JOIN loan ON deal.id = loan."dealID" 
  JOIN person ON person.id = pp."personID" 
WHERE 
  party."partyRoleID" = 1 
  AND (
    person."primaryEmail" ILIKE '%' || search || '%' 
    OR person."fullName" ILIKE '%' || search || '%'
  ) 
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      1 
    FROM 
      "DealParty" dp2 
      JOIN party party2 ON dp2."partyID" = party2.id 
      JOIN "PartyPerson" pp2 ON party2.id = pp2."partyID" 
      JOIN person person2 ON pp2."personID" = person2.id 
    WHERE 
      dp2."dealID" = deal.id 
      AND party2."partyRoleID" = 2 
      AND person2."primaryEmail" = hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-user-id'
  ) 
ORDER BY   
      CASE
        WHEN order_by_full_name THEN person."fullName" :: text
        WHEN order_by_email THEN person."primaryEmail" :: text
        WHEN order_by_deal_status THEN deal."dealStatusID" :: text
        WHEN order_by_loan_status THEN loan."loanStatusID" :: text
        WHEN order_by_created_at THEN deal."_createdAt" :: text
        ELSE deal."_lastUpdatedAt" :: text
      END
LIMIT 
  limit_param 
OFFSET 
  offset_param;
END;
$function$
```

I also want to pass an `order_direction` flag to control the order of the results into either ascending or descending order but I am really not sure how this query needs to be modified to achieve this.

Comment: I've edited question tags. MySQL and PostgreSQL use entirely different syntaxes for stored procedures and functions. If you really need a solution for both platforms, you're better off asking a new question for MySQL and including the MySQL version of the function.

Comment: I found this: [dynamic order by sql postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855818/dynamic-order-by-sql-postgresql)